# How to use use custom editorkit with HTMLEditorkit?

Tags: java, swing, htmleditorkit

I am making a scientific calculator in which you can write a complete expression and then it will calculate your answer.
To display the expression I'll be using JEditorPane.

The main problem is:

1. Displaying Fraction as is written by hand(numerator over denominator)
2. Displaying powers

The solution I have found for the above two problems are:

1. Using [this](http://java-sl.com/fraction_view.html) editorKit to display Fractions.
2. Using HTML to display powers.

Now, the problem I am facing is that I have to use two editorKits i.e HTMLEditorKit and FractionEditorKit and when I switch from FractionEditorKit to HTMLEditorKit all my formatting is lost.

```
                 editorPane.setEditorKit(new FractionEditorKit());
                 StyledDocument doc=(StyledDocument) editorPane.getDocument();
                 SimpleAttributeSet attrs=new SimpleAttributeSet();
                  attrs.addAttribute(FractionEditorKit.FRACTION_ATTRIBUTE_NAME,"");
                SimpleAttributeSet normalAttrs=new SimpleAttributeSet();
                try {

                    doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), "Fraction ", normalAttrs);
                doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), String.format("1234\r5678"), attrs);
                }

                catch (BadLocationException ex) {
                }

                }

HTMLEditorKit kitH = new HTMLEditorKit();
HTMLDocument docH=(HTMLDocument) editorPane.getDocument();
editorPane.setEditorKit(kitH);
            editorPane.setDocument(docH);


                try {
                    kitH.insertHTML(docH, editorPane.getDocument().getLength(), "<HTML>10<sup>4</sup></HTML>",0,0,null);

                } catch (BadLocationException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Comment: Post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also, specify why what you are doing is not working.

Comment: I hav updated my question kindly make tym to answer it.

Comment: This is not a [mcve]. Please read the link again.

Comment: Can you please tell me as to which aspect my question is lacking in ?

Comment: The code is not Complete and not Verifiable. Read the link please.